# Java SortedMap implemented with List of values

Tags: java

I want to have a Sorted map as follows:

> srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol as **keys**

and a **List** of **values** as

packetLength, timeArrival for each key.

Is it possible to implement them in separate classes? I am confused if it will work this way.

#### Update:

I am getting an error indicating im not overriding abstract method compareTo(). Can you help me with it?

```
package myclassifier;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class Flows implements Serializable, Comparable {

    String srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol;

    public int compareTo(Flows other) {
        int res = this.srcAddr.compareTo(other.srcAddr);
        
        if (res != 0) {
            return res;
        }
        
        res = this.dstAddr.compareTo(other.dstAddr);
        if (res != 0) {
            return res;
        }
        
        res = this.srcPort.compareTo(other.srcPort);
        if (res != 0) {
            return res;
        }
        
        res = this.dstPort.compareTo(other.dstPort);
        if (res != 0) {
            return res;
        }
        
        return this.protocol.compareTo(other.protocol);

      
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((dstAddr == null) ? 0 : dstAddr.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dstPort == null) ? 0 : dstPort.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((srcAddr == null) ? 0 : srcAddr.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((srcPort == null) ? 0 : srcPort.hashCode());
        return result;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        Flows other = (Flows) obj;
        
        if (dstAddr == null) {
            if (other.dstAddr != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr))
            return false;

        if (dstPort == null) {
            if (other.dstPort != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dstPort.equals(other.dstPort))
            return false;

        if (srcAddr == null) {
            if (other.srcAddr != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr))
            return false;

        if (srcPort == null) {
            if (other.srcPort != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!srcPort.equals(other.srcPort))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a, say a 'MyKey' class with srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort and protocol  as member variables of it. You have to carefully override the `equals` and `hashCode` method of this class. Also this class has to implement the [Comparable](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) interface to indicate how your ordering will be determined based on member fields.

You can implement a class MyValue to have packetLength, timeArrival etc as members. This will be the value you want to store in your map.

Use [TreeMap](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) to store MyValue against MyKey.

Comment: public int compareTo(Flows arg0) {
        if(this.srcAddr == arg0.srcAddr &&
                this.dstAddr == arg0.dstAddr &&
                    this.srcPort == arg0.srcPort &&
                        this.dstPort == arg0.dstPort &&
                            this.protocol == arg0.protocol)
                return 0;


is it correct? i  have a problem with return part.

Comment: First let me know how are you looking to order the MyKey objects then I can help you in implementing this method. For example if there are two MyKey objects, then tell me your business logic which you will apply to determine which object is first and which is second.

Comment: I am looking for flows in a pcap file. A flow is a set of packets all have the same 5-tuple : srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol.
then i want to examine each packet to see if they belong to a flow, if they r, i will extract some statics for each packet. 

i was thinking of order of fields not order of objects. may be i was wrong, i dont know if i am doing right.

Comment: Well then first finalize your requirement :)

Answer (score 1):

you can implement different classes one for the key

```
public class Packet implements Serializable, Comparable {

String srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort;


public int compareTo(Object arg0) {
    // your sorting logic here
    return ...;
}


@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((dstAddr == null) ? 0 : dstAddr.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((dstPort == null) ? 0 : dstPort.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((srcAddr == null) ? 0 : srcAddr.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((srcPort == null) ? 0 : srcPort.hashCode());
    return result;
}


@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Packet other = (Packet) obj;
    if (dstAddr == null) {
        if (other.dstAddr != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr))
        return false;
    if (dstPort == null) {
        if (other.dstPort != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!dstPort.equals(other.dstPort))
        return false;
    if (srcAddr == null) {
        if (other.srcAddr != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr))
        return false;
    if (srcPort == null) {
        if (other.srcPort != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!srcPort.equals(other.srcPort))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

And one for the data

```
public class Payload {

Integer packetLength;
Date timeArrival;
```

}

then when you put payload with a certain key in a sorted map it will be placed in order according to the compareTo method

Comment: i think i wasnt clear.
im looking for TCPFlows first, and then finding characteristics of each packet inside that Flow. Flow is defined as a set of packets all between certain source and destination addresses. 
what i want to do is for example:

srcAddr = x
dstAddr = y
srcPort = 
dstPort = 80
protocol = http

if there already doesnt exist a record with these information, i will add it to my table and then write some statics about s packet belonging to that flow and so on. it might be 16 packets belonging to a flow and so on. 

so what I thought was having a list for each packet inside a flow.

Answer (score 0):

You want sort your map based on its keys or values? Do you want the keys to be sorted alphabetically or in the order you've specified above? Overall it shouldn't be too difficult:

```
SorterMap<String, List> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<String, List>(myComparator);
mySortedMap.put("srcAddr", Arrays.asList(new Object[] {packetLengthValue, arrivalTimeValue}))
```

Where you should implement `myComparator` to sort the keys according to your requirements.

Comment: i need to have all 5-tuple as my key srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort and protocol.

Comment: and sorted the way i wrote them down.